# Axios 400 Bad request using post method in React js

Tags: reactjs, post, axios

IncidentDataExport =async (report_type) => {

```
    if (report_type == 'excel') {
        let data = {
            r_type: 'excel',
            incident_number: `${this.state.incident_number}`
         
        }
        console.log("incifffffffff==>",this.state.incident_number)

         await axios.post(`/internal_incident/export-incident/`,data,{
            responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        }).then(res => {
            var blob = new Blob([res.data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
            saveAs(blob, `${this.state.incident_number}.xlsx`);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log("eeeeeeeeeeeeeee",err);
        })
    }

    if (report_type == 'pdf') {
        // DownloadIncidentInPdf(this.state, this.state.incident_number, 'a2');
        let data = {
            r_type: 'pdf',
            incident_number: `${this.state.incident_number}`
        }
        await axios.post(`/internal_incident/export-incident/`,data, {
            responseType: 'blob',
        }).then(res => {
            saveAs(res.data, `${this.state.incident_number}.pdf`);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log("errrrrr",err);
        })
    }
}
```

{/*  this.IncidentDataExport('excel')}> */}
                                        
                                             this.IncidentDataExport('excel')} />
                                        
                                        
                                             this.IncidentDataExport('pdf')} />

Comment: You can't use Promise syntax and async-await keywords together

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Promise syntax and async-await keywords together. You can either use Promise or async-await at a time.

```
IncidentDataExport = (report_type) => {
    if (report_type == 'excel') {
        let data = {
            r_type: 'excel',
            incident_number: `${this.state.incident_number}`
         
        }
        console.log("incifffffffff==>",this.state.incident_number)

         axios.post(`/internal_incident/export-incident/`,data,{
            responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        }).then(res => {
            var blob = new Blob([res.data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
            saveAs(blob, `${this.state.incident_number}.xlsx`);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log("eeeeeeeeeeeeeee",err);
        })
    }
}
```